# OpenGL - Trying to add texture to triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, mesh

I am trying to add a stop sign texture to a triangle in opengl.

But for some reason the image is coming up weird like I have the coordinates in the wrong order and the image is 1, mirrored and 2, not angled correctly:

[image]

I believe I set the texture coordinates correct but I am unsure. Have i got the texture coordinates in the wrong order?

Here is the code I have for it:

```
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <graphics_framework.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
using namespace graphics_framework;
using namespace glm;

mesh m;
effect eff;
target_camera cam;
texture tex;

bool load_content() {
  // Construct geometry object
  geometry geom;
  // Create triangle data
  // Positions
  vector<vec3> positions{vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), vec3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)};
  // *********************************
  // Define texture coordinates for triangle
  vector<vec2> tex_coords{ vec2(0.0f, 0.0f), vec2(1.0f, 0.0f), vec2(0.5f, 1.0f) };
  // *********************************
  // Add to the geometry
  geom.add_buffer(positions, BUFFER_INDEXES::POSITION_BUFFER);
  // *********************************
  // Add texture coordinate buffer to geometry
  geom.add_buffer(tex_coords, BUFFER_INDEXES::TEXTURE_COORDS_0);
  // *********************************

  // Create mesh object
  m = mesh(geom);

  // Load in texture shaders here
  eff.add_shader("27_Texturing_Shader/simple_texture.vert", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  eff.add_shader("27_Texturing_Shader/simple_texture.frag", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  // *********************************
  // Build effect
  eff.build();
  // Load texture "textures/sign.jpg"
  tex = texture("textures/sign.jpg");
  // *********************************

  // Set camera properties
  cam.set_position(vec3(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f));
  cam.set_target(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
  auto aspect = static_cast<float>(renderer::get_screen_width()) / static_cast<float>(renderer::get_screen_height());
  cam.set_projection(quarter_pi<float>(), aspect, 2.414f, 1000.0f);

  return true;
}

bool update(float delta_time) {
  // Update the camera
  cam.update(delta_time);
  return true;
}

bool render() {
  // Bind effect
  renderer::bind(eff);
  // Create MVP matrix
  auto M = m.get_transform().get_transform_matrix();
  auto V = cam.get_view();
  auto P = cam.get_projection();
  auto MVP = P * V * M;
  // Set MVP matrix uniform
  glUniformMatrix4fv(eff.get_uniform_location("MVP"), // Location of uniform
                     1,                               // Number of values - 1 mat4
                     GL_FALSE,                        // Transpose the matrix?
                     value_ptr(MVP));                 // Pointer to matrix data

  // *********************************
  // Bind texture to renderer
  renderer::bind(tex, 0);
  // Set the texture value for the shader here
  glUniform1i(eff.get_uniform_location("tex"), 0);
  // *********************************

  // Render the mesh
  renderer::render(m);

  return true;
}

void main() {
  // Create application
  app application("27_Texturing_Shader");
  // Set load content, update and render methods
  application.set_load_content(load_content);
  application.set_update(update);
  application.set_render(render);
  // Run application
  application.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the order of your vertex positions and texture coordinates do not match. The first position is the top corner (assuming y is up), but the first texture coordinate is the bottom left corner of the image. Moving the last texture coordinate to the front should do the trick.

Your texture is probably mirrored along the y-axis. OpenGL expects the texture lines to be bottom-up, but most image libraries provide them top-down. Depends on what library you use to load the image. And of course, it will depend on the side from which you view the triangle.